# Autocorrelation of a stochastic process

Tags: arima, econometrics, stochastic-processes

What does it mean to compute the autocorrelation between two different time istances in a time series? I don't well understand the concept, which is the sense of measuring between two time istances of the same series? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

auto-correlation is computed on the n pairs of values k periods apart . For example if we have 60 observations we can compute the auto-correlation of lag 1 using 59 pairs. likewise we can use 48 pairs to compute the relationship between values 12 period apart.

autocorrelation is an ensemble measure based upon a number of relationships for a particular lag (temporal distance)

Comment: I don't catch well the idea. For example, in a sample autocorrelation plot, the presence of autocorellation at lag 3, what does tell to us? That there is a correlation between what? Thanks

Comment: That would indicate a correlation between observations that are 3 time units apart.